# How to use the built-in procedure to manage relationship index in Neo4J 3.x

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I'm using

`CALL db.index.explicit.auto.seekRelationships('user', '15229100-b20e-11e3-80d3-6150cb20a1b9')`

procedure in Neo4J 3.x to return all relationships where key `user` equals the id.

However, in previous 2.x version I was also able to filter those relationships by the relationship type using

`WHERE TYPE(rel)='TO'`

specifically:

`START rel=relationship:relationship_auto_index(user='15229100-b20e-11e3-80d3-6150cb20a1b9') WHERE TYPE(rel)='TO' WITH DISTINCT rel MATCH (ctx:Context) WHERE rel.context = ctx.uid AND (ctx.name="neo4j5" ) RETURN rel`

How do I do that same thing in Neo4J 3.x?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the APOC procedure [apoc.index.relationships](https://neo4j-contrib.github.io/neo4j-apoc-procedures/#_index_queries).

For example:

```
CALL apoc.index.relationships('TO', 'user:15229100-b20e-11e3-80d3-6150cb20a1b9')
YIELD rel
MATCH (ctx:Context)
WHERE rel.context = ctx.uid AND ctx.name="neo4j5"
RETURN rel;
```